# MAILTO is not working for CRON. How can I fix this?

Tags: email, cron

I have setup cronjob for the root user.
However when the cron fail I should receive an email from the cronjob because I have set MAILTO like this in /etc/crontab :

```
MAILTO=my@email.com
```

I have installed mailx using

```
yum install mailx
```

But when I look at the cron log I get these lines :

```
Feb 23 14:13:01 internal crond[6858]: (root) CMD (/var/www/vded/build/bin/sync.sh)
Feb 23 14:13:01 internal crond[6857]: (root) MAIL (mailed 79 bytes of output but got status 0x0001 )
```

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE :**

- I installed mailx and sendmail using yum.
- I started sendmail.
- So now sending an email is working from the command line!

I get this error in the maillog :

```
Feb 23 16:06:01 internal sendmail[7210]: o1NG61cd007210: from=root, size=425, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201002231606.o1NG61cd007210@internal.fff.com>, relay=root@localhost
Feb 23 16:06:01 internal sendmail[7211]: o1NG61hT007211: from=<root@internal.fff.com>, size=732, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201002231606.o1NG61cd007210@internal.fff.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Feb 23 16:06:01 internal sendmail[7210]: o1NG61cd007210: to=root, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30425, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (o1NG61hT007211 Message accepted for delivery)
Feb 23 16:06:01 internal sendmail[7212]: o1NG61hT007211: to=<root@internal.fff.com>, ctladdr=<root@internal.fff.com> (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30972, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

internal.fff.com is the name of the server.

**UPDATE :**

So in fact if I put the `MAILTO=my@email.com` as the first line of my crontab (using `crontab -e`) it is working.

Why is it not working by setting the `MAILTO` in `/etc/crontab` ?

Thanks

Comment: What do the logs from your mail server say?  How is mailx configured to send mail?

Comment: Also, try sending something manually using mailx and compare the resulting logs on the mail server.

Comment: /var/log/maillog is empty
I haven't configured mailx

Comment: Can you send mail from the command line?

Comment: Could you answer the recommendations mentioned here first, please? Try sending a mail from the command line, please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change "From:" field for emails from Cron?](http://serverfault.com/questions/121121/how-to-change-from-field-for-emails-from-cron)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So to answer my question :

- Install mailx `yum install mailx`
- Install sendmail `yum install sendmail`
- Start sendmail
- Put the `MAILTO` line into the crontab using `crontab -e` : `MAILTO=my@email.com` and not in `/etc/crontab`

Comment: I just noticed on CentOS 6.5 (w/cronie) that `/etc/crontab` does not specify defaults. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3724/etc-cron-daily-foo-send-email-to-a-particular-user-instead-of-root#comment201977_3724

Comment: Short and simple

Answer (score 0):

you can simplify this by installing nullmailer instead of sendmail (or exim4, or postfix, etc.).

if it's not working, as mine was not, and you're sending to a webmail service such as gmail: make sure you didn't put any filters on it. I in fact had a filter on anything from cron, to bypass the inbox. that's why I wasn't seeing anything from my cron jobs.

Answer (score 0):

My `/var/log/maillog` was showing that `crontab` (with `MAILTO=root`) was trying to send email to both `root` and  `root@my_fqdn` (where `my_fqdn` is like server.something.com).   Per the log, sending to `root` was successful and `root@my_fqdn` failed, yet I found not message in `/var/mail/root`.  Here's the relevant `/var/log/maillog` snippet:

```
Aug 16 17:49:02 ip-10-64-21-125 sendmail[22211]: v7GHn2Tr022211: from=root, size=742, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201708161749.v7GHn2Tr022211@my_fqdn>, relay=root@localhost
Aug 16 17:49:02 ip-10-64-21-125 sendmail[22212]: v7GHn2Ws022212: from=<root@my_fqdn>, size=1061, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201708161749.v7GHn2Tr022211@my_fqdn>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Aug 16 17:49:02 ip-10-64-21-125 sendmail[22211]: v7GHn2Tr022211: to=root, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30742, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (v7GHn2Ws022212 Message accepted for delivery)
Aug 16 17:49:02 ip-10-64-21-125 sendmail[22214]: v7GHn2Ws022212: to=<root@my_fqdn>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=121061, relay=my_fqdn. [10.0.0.1], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by my_fqdn.
```

However, [per this tip](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230599/sendmail-messages-not-delivered-after-fixing-name-resolution), mail now shows up in `/var/mail/root`.  The problem was `/etc/hosts` needed to have a line added so `my_fqdn` would resolve *as a domain* (notice the dot at the end): 
`127.0.0.1   my_fqdn.`

**Note:** The way this is working now is that the message is still failing to be received properly, but is bouncing back in a way that lands it in `/var/mail/root` (notice `stat=Local configuration error` below in `/var/log/maillog` snippet).

```
Aug 16 17:50:04 ip-10-64-21-125 sendmail[22223]: v7GHo4ZJ022223: from=root, size=742, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201708161750.v7GHo4ZJ022223@my_fqdn>, relay=root@localhost
Aug 16 17:50:04 ip-10-64-21-125 sendmail[22224]: v7GHo4MT022224: from=<root@my_fqdn>, size=1061, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201708161750.v7GHo4ZJ022223@my_fqdn>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Aug 16 17:50:04 ip-10-64-21-125 sendmail[22223]: v7GHo4ZJ022223: to=root, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30742, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (v7GHo4MT022224 Message accepted for delivery)
Aug 16 17:50:04 ip-10-64-21-125 sendmail[22226]: v7GHo4MT022224: SYSERR(root): my_fqdn. config error: mail loops back to me (MX problem?)
Aug 16 17:50:04 ip-10-64-21-125 sendmail[22226]: v7GHo4MT022224: to=<root@my_fqdn>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=121061, relay=my_fqdn. [127.0.0.1], dsn=5.3.5, stat=Local configuration error
Aug 16 17:50:04 ip-10-64-21-125 sendmail[22226]: v7GHo4MT022224: v7GHo4MT022226: DSN: Local configuration error
Aug 16 17:50:04 ip-10-64-21-125 sendmail[22227]: v7GHo4Ml022227: localhost [127.0.0.1] did not issue MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN during connection to MTA
Aug 16 17:50:04 ip-10-64-21-125 sendmail[22226]: v7GHo4MT022226: to=root, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=62294, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
Aug 16 17:50:04 ip-10-64-21-125 sendmail[22226]: v7GHo4MT022226: to=<root@my_fqdn>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=62294, relay=my_fqdn., dsn=5.3.5, stat=Local configuration error
Aug 16 17:50:04 ip-10-64-21-125 sendmail[22226]: v7GHo4MT022226: v7GHo4MU022226: return to sender: Local configuration error
Aug 16 17:50:04 ip-10-64-21-125 sendmail[22226]: v7GHo4MU022226: to=root, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=33318, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```