# ssmtp change " From: "root" <xy@com>" root name

Tags: linux, email-server

My root user send emails with ssmtp. However I can't change "From: *root* ..." root name. Is there any way to send email with another name without using another user?

Tried:

echo 'From: "New name" ' | ssmtp to@gmail.com -v

Comment: @cornernote's answer should be the solution here. Also check there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202791/how-to-change-sender-name-in-ssmtp

Answer (score 23):

You can set up a reverse alias in `/etc/ssmtp/revaliases`

`root:someone@yourdomain.tld`

it's hidden at the bottom of the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ssmtp).

Answer (score 13):

Add the following in Your /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf file and You will capable to set any name and email during runtime :

```
FromLineOverride=YES
```

Comment: This is simpler than messing with `/etc/ssmtp/revaliases`, especially when `ssmtp` is run with `-t -Cssmtp.conf`.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you switch from ssmtp to msmtp since ssmtp is not actively developed any more. msmtp provides all the same features as ssmtp plus more.  In particular, with msmtp you can [set the from setting](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/doc/msmtp.html#Envelope_002dfrom-address) to control who the mail appears to be sent from.

Comment: This is not quite true - even in 2018 sSMTP seems widely used for it's simplest tasks. For instance all Ubuntu LTS releases ship with latest avail sSMTP package. It does it's job.

Comment: I was able to do that with msmtp with `set_from_header on`.
An aliases file with a `default: ...` entry is also useful

Answer (score 5):

Try option -Ffull_name, ex:

```
ssmtp login@mail.com -F"Look at me"
```

i'll change full name.
there is also -f for changing sender email, ex:

```
ssmtp -f"helper@world" -F"SuperHero" save@our.world
```

Comment: Works only with `FromLineOverride=YES` in ssmtp.conf.

Answer (score 4):

Change the 'From' text by editing `/etc/passwd` to receive mail from 'YOUR NAME HERE' instead of just 'root'.

```
chfn -f 'YOUR NAME HERE' root
```

Check it using `grep root /etc/passwd`

```
root:x:0:0:YOUR NAME HERE,,,:/root:/bin/bash
```

[Found it here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSMTP#Forward_to_a_Gmail_mail_server) and it worked a treat!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like FromLineOverride=YES doesn't work anymore.

I guess GMAIL is not allowing this now. But I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using **ssmtp** and, even though I tried the other solutions, none of them worked for me.

However, it worked for me with GMail by defining the "From" field as:

```
...
From: Your Name Here <your_email_here@gmail.com>
...
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This works for overriding the name, but not the address. It still shows as whatever your real gmail address is that is acting as the SMTP relay.

Answer (score 0):

The `-F` option works if you are specifying the email params on the ssmtp command line, e.g.

`echo "Test email" | ssmtp -F"New name" -v to@gmail.com`

If you want all emails sent from root@ to come from a certain name, you can change the Linux user information as described in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30290548/550712):

`chfn -f "New name" root`

"What this does is setting/changing the real name for that user in the finger information (stored in the /etc/passwd file--see the [chfn man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chfn.1.html))."

**Update**  Even after updating the finger information, cron is still sending email from "root", not using my "New name". Some versions of cron support a `MAILFROM=` line, but not mine (see [this article](https://serverfault.com/a/437319/166311)).