# How can I change the sender's name for email messages sent by cron

Tags: linux, email, cron

We have several nearly identical servers with a fairly classic server-NN naming convention, each running cron jobs that we like to monitor via email. There are is a group of users, who receive the email messages from these cron jobs and they all come from:

```
From: "(Cron Daemon)" <user-x@server-NN.brandle.net>
```

where user-x is invariant but server-NN changes with each server. I'd like for the emails to come from:

```
From: "Cron Server-NN" <user-x@server-NN.brandle.net>
```

I've tried setting the 'full-name' for 'user-x' but that had no effect. There has to be a way to handle this more cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

Most recent versions of `cronie` can use the MAIFROM variable to set the envelope sender address. This obviously requires that your distribution uses `cronie` to provide `cron`.

On distribution non supporting MAILFROM, you can use a shell script to obtain the required behavior. In this case, it will be the shell script that sends the email, rather than `cron` itself.

For more information, please read [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/121121/how-to-change-from-field-for-emails-from-cron) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/438843/how-to-customise-email-headers-from-vixie-cron-debian-and-msmtp/).