# exim: Rewrite "From" header to envelope "FROM"

Tags: exim

Cron sends emails with the "From" header always set to "From: root@example.com (Cron Daemon)" for all users, even though the envelope address (seen in the "Delivered-To" header in received email) is the user's correct email address. Is it possible to create a header rewrite rule which fixes the "From" header for outgoing emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file in `/etc/exim4/conf.d/rewrite`, for example `10-cron-rewrite`, with the contents:

```
root@ETC_MAILNAME   "${if match {$header_from:}{.*(Cron Daemon).*} {$sender_address}fail}"  f
```