# Cron Email Locally

Tags: centos, cron, sendmail

I have my crontab configured to mail to a specific address, for example purposes lets say "test@test.com".  test.com is also the host name of my box, however I have my mx email records configured externally to point at gmail domain.  All emails work fine going to test.com and I log into there no problem.

However with crontab and I'm assuming other processes it sends the email locally, again assuming it thinks it should be accepting all emails going to test.com .

Suggestions on how to fix this without breaking outgoing emails sending from the test.com address?

Updated, the mail server is sendmail here is the config file: http://pastebin.com/4sSApB1y

Comment: Which MTA do you have installed? What's the configuration?

Comment: updated with info

Comment: try to monitor /var/log/mail.log and verify that cron is sending to test@test.com. It is hard to believe that you local smtp forwards all mails to the right destination but not the messages from cron.

Comment: I never said that Tim, if I try to mail -s "Test" test@test.com it goes locally as well.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/344105/outgoing-mail-from-linux-not-being-delivered/344189#344189

Comment: adamo has the correct answer above ^ very nice fix thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want mail send to test.com not to be delivered locally, then remove the domain from the sendmail config file. It is usually under `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc` with the option name `LOCAL_DOMAIN(test.com)`. Comment that out with `dnl` at the beginning of the line. If you can't find test.com in that file, search it using grep in /etc/mail and remove it if is there to set local delivery of that domain.

Comment: Commented out and restarted sendmail to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the computer. Anything that's *not* `test.com` would be sufficient. After all, this computer almost certainly isn't. Perhaps `chief.test.com` or `cortana.test.com`?

Comment: haha I love it.  The problem is Michael that I still want outgoing mail to come from test.com and renaming the computer something else appears to break that.

Comment: So, [place your desired address in the `From:` field](http://serverfault.com/a/121154/126632), like you do everywhere else.