# Stop cron jobs from sending emails as root but allow sendmail to work

Tags: postfix, bash, cron, sendmail, ubuntu-20.04

I've recently got Postfix working as a send only MTA relaying through Google Workspace (formerly Google G Suite). I would now like to send emails after completed cron jobs to my personal email. The problem I initially faced was that my server was sending out two emails, one to `personal-email@hotmail.com` and the other to `root@example.com` with the latter bouncing back a MAILER-DAEMON reply as this account doesn't exist.

This was my initial cron job located at `/etc/cron.d/google-drive-backup`:

```
59 11 * * * root /root/scripts/google-drive-backup.sh && mail --append="From:Root <no-reply@example.com>" --append="Reply-To:webmaster@example.com" personal-email@hotmail.com
```

I did research on these forums and came across suppressing the output by using `>/dev/null 2>&1` which works if I place it directly after the script:

```
59 11 * * * root /root/scripts/google-drive-backup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I can confirm no emails are being sent as the mail log at `/var/log/mail.log` is empty. However, suppressing the output has no affect when using it in conjunction with the `mail` command:

```
59 11 * * * root /root/scripts/google-drive-backup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 && mail --append="From:Root <no-reply@example.com>" --append="Reply-To:webmaster@example.com" personal-email@hotmail.com
```

or

```
59 11 * * * root /root/scripts/google-drive-backup.sh && mail --append="From:Root <no-reply@example.com>" --append="Reply-To:webmaster@example.com" personal-email@hotmail.com >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Essentially I would like to disable crontab's default email feature and use sendmail so that I can customise the subject and email headers.

Comment: You can redirect *stderr* to *stdout* and still pipe that mix to mail, like this: `command 2>&1 | mail recipient` - the `fd>&fd` syntax is not limited to cases where you plan to discard output!

Comment: @anx How do I drop the output altogether? I want to only send an email if the script completes without any errors, but I don't want the output from the script to be in the message body of the email which your example does.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change "From:" field for emails from Cron?](https://serverfault.com/questions/121121/how-to-change-from-field-for-emails-from-cron)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up suppressing the `stdout` and `stderr` to a null file and then using two ampersands to create a subject with the `echo` command that pipes into the `mail` command to complete the rest. Here is my finished cron job:

```
59 11 * * * root /root/scripts/google-drive-backup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "Cron job has finished at $(date +'\%d/\%m/\%Y') $(date +'(\%H:\%M:\%S)')" | mail --subject="WordPress Backup Complete" --append="From:Root <webmaster@example.com>" --append="Reply-To:webmaster@example.com" personal-email@yahoo.co.uk
```